# Name of background job started from EXIT trap is wrong

Tags: bash, job-control

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m

atexit() {
    sleep 1 &
    jobs
}

trap atexit EXIT

echo Hello world
```

Produces this output:

```
$ bash ./foo.sh
Hello world
[1]+  Running                 echo Hello world &
```

Why is the name of the background job `echo Hello world &` and not `sleep 1 &`?

Comment: Seems like a bash thing. Running your script with `dash foo.sh` prints `sleep 1` instead. Same for `zsh`. Interestingly, `ksh` shows `<command unknown>` instead.